# Attempting to write a pyspark function to connect to SQL Server with Databricks on Apache Spart

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to write a function that I can use to connect to SQL Server from Databricks.

My attempt is as follows:

```
def readFromDb():
         jdbcDF = (spark.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver.database.windows.net;database=mydatabase")
        .option("user", 'myusername')
        .option("query", 'query')
        .option("password", 'myquery')
        .load()    
          )
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near &#39;)&#39;.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2138842992712231> in <module>
----> 1 readFromDb()

<command-2138842992712230> in readFromDb()
      1 def readFromDb():
----> 2          jdbcDF = (spark.read
```

Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: maybe the spacing?

Comment: I changed the spacing, but got the same error

Comment: oh you `query` is a string `'query'`, not `query` object?

Comment: I kept on getting the message that I needed to include 'query' or 'dbtable'

Comment: I actually don't want 'query', but the code wouldn't execute without it.

Comment: yes but in your code above, you're using **literal string** `.option("query", 'query')`

Comment: Ah, You must pass a query, that's required, any query works

Comment: Without the string I get the error:  ```
NameError: name 'query' is not defined```

Comment: Anyone have any additional thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the use and password options to the actual values of your DB and the query option to the query you want to run.
also don't forget to add return at the end of the function.

e.g:
`.option("query", 'select * from information_schema.tables')`

Comment: Hi Walking, thanks for reaching out. I added your line of code to my original code, but I got the error:  ```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Option 'dbtable' is required. Option 'query' is not applicable while writing```
The full code is as follows:
```df.write.mode("append") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("query", 'select * from information_schema.tables')\
    .save()```

Comment: I think I need to change the write.mode to something else....